# Why my bootstrap collapse navbar won't work

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So im trying to create some navbar using bootstrap and make it able to collapse but it won't work
please help

This are my line of codes:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="WebLogo"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button> 
 
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Service</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Location</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Connect</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Sign in</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Appreciate it for the help, thankyou

Comment: what is the error about?

Answer (score 1):

You must add jQuery and popper.js link or file to your project

jQuery

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

visit  [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) document

Comment: I already add those link at the beginning but it didn't change anything

Comment: To add on this question, my dropdown button isn't working also. i tried to just copy paste the template from bootstrap but when i run the code on my PC it just don't work